# Using bigquery to decode from unicode to Hebrew

Tags: google-bigquery

Using Google bigquery standardSQL, I would like to decode the following unicode string into Hebrew:

`&#x5D0;&#x5DC;&#x5D3;&#x5DF; &#x5EA;&#x5D7;&#x5D1;&#x5D5;&#x5E8;&#x5D4; &#x5DE;&#x5E1;&#x5DB;&#x5DE;&#x5EA; &#x5D0;&#x5EA; &#x5D4;&#x5E8;&#x5D1;&#x5E2;&#x5D5;&#x5DF; &#x5D4;&#x5E8;&#x5D0;&#x5E9;&#x5D5;&#x5DF; &#x5DC;&#x5E9;&#x5E0;&#x5EA; 2021 &#x5E2;&#x5DD; &#x5D4;&#x5DE;&#x5E9;&#x5DA; &#x5E9;&#x5D9;&#x5E4;&#x5D5;&#x5E8; &#x5DE;&#x5E9;&#x5DE;&#x5E2;&#x5D5;&#x5EA;&#x5D9; &#x5D1;&#x5E8;&#x5D5;&#x5D5;&#x5D7;&#x5D9;&#x5D5;&#x5EA; &#x5D4;&#x5E4;&#x5E2;&#x5D9;&#x5DC;&#x5D5;&#x5EA;`

Note that ; is used to separate a single Hebrew character from the next one. An empty space separates a word from the next one. There is also one number (2021) that ought to be inserted into the decode-result as is. The End result (in Hebrew) should read:

אלדן תחבורה מסכמת את הרבעון הראשון לשנת 2021 עם המשך שיפור משמעותי ברווחיות הפעילות

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below solution

```
create temp function decode(word string) as ((
  select if(starts_with(word, '&#x'), 
    safe.code_points_to_string(array(
      select cast(value as int64)
      from unnest(split(replace(word, '&#', '0'),';')) value
      where not value = ''
    )), 
    word)
));
select (
    select string_agg(decode(word), ' ')
    from unnest(split(txt, ' ')) word
  ) as Hebrew_txt
from `project.dataset.table`
```

if to apply to sample data in your question

```
with `project.dataset.table` as (
  select '&#x5D0;&#x5DC;&#x5D3;&#x5DF; &#x5EA;&#x5D7;&#x5D1;&#x5D5;&#x5E8;&#x5D4; &#x5DE;&#x5E1;&#x5DB;&#x5DE;&#x5EA; &#x5D0;&#x5EA; &#x5D4;&#x5E8;&#x5D1;&#x5E2;&#x5D5;&#x5DF; &#x5D4;&#x5E8;&#x5D0;&#x5E9;&#x5D5;&#x5DF; &#x5DC;&#x5E9;&#x5E0;&#x5EA; 2021 &#x5E2;&#x5DD; &#x5D4;&#x5DE;&#x5E9;&#x5DA; &#x5E9;&#x5D9;&#x5E4;&#x5D5;&#x5E8; &#x5DE;&#x5E9;&#x5DE;&#x5E2;&#x5D5;&#x5EA;&#x5D9; &#x5D1;&#x5E8;&#x5D5;&#x5D5;&#x5D7;&#x5D9;&#x5D5;&#x5EA; &#x5D4;&#x5E4;&#x5E2;&#x5D9;&#x5DC;&#x5D5;&#x5EA;' txt
)
```

output is

[image]

Below is adjusted function to handle cases with reserved/special characters such as ,#$@*(){}.,&^%!?. etc.

```
create temp function decode(word string) as ((
  select if(starts_with(word, '&#x'), 
    safe.code_points_to_string(array(
      select ifnull(safe_cast(value as int64), ascii(value))
      from unnest(split(replace(word, '&#', '0'),';')) value
      where not value = ''
    )), 
    word)
));
```

Comment: Works nicely on my original example Mikhail! It fails when I run your code against similar input that contains reserved/special characters such as ,#$@*(){}.,&^%!?. I then get an error such as Bad int64 value: , Can you please revise your code so it works on an input like this one: &#x5E9;&#x5D1;&#x5D7;&#x5D9;&#x5DD; &#x5DC;&#x5E1;&#x5D5;&#x5E7;&#x5D5;&#x5DC;&#x5D5;&#x5D1;&#x5E1;&#x5E7;&#x5D9;, &#x5D4;&#x5D0;&#x5E8;&#x5D9;&#x5E1;: &#x5D9;&#x5D3;&#x5E2;&#x5E0;&#x5D5; &#x5E9;&#x5EA;&#x5D4;&#x5D9;&#x5D4; &#x5DE;&#x5DC;&#x5D7;&#x5DE;&#x5D4;